# Update multiple rows using a case statement only updates 1 row

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I would like to update one column but multiple rows in one table using a case statement.
this is update statement:

```
UPDATE UDSDiagnosisGroups
SET UDSDiagnosisCategoryID = 
    CASE WHEN LineDisplay IN ('1-2', '3', '4', '4a', '4b') THEN (SELECT UDSDiagnosisCategoryID 
                                                                 FROM UDSDiagnosisCategories
                                                                 WHERE UDSDiagnosisCategory = 'Selected Infectious and Parasitic Diseases') 
         WHEN LineDisplay IN ('5', '6') THEN (SELECT UDSDiagnosisCategoryID 
                                              FROM UDSDiagnosisCategories
                                              WHERE UDSDiagnosisCategory = 'Selected Diseases of the Respiratory System')
         WHEN LineDisplay IN ('7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '14a') THEN (SELECT UDSDiagnosisCategoryID 
                                                                                        FROM UDSDiagnosisCategories
                                                                                        WHERE UDSDiagnosisCategory = 'Selected Other Medical Conditions')
         WHEN LineDisplay IN ('15', '16', '17') THEN (SELECT UDSDiagnosisCategoryID 
                                                      FROM UDSDiagnosisCategories
                                                      WHERE UDSDiagnosisCategory = ' Selected Childhood Conditions (limited to ages 0 through 17)')
         WHEN LineDisplay IN ('18', '19', '19a', '20a', '20b', '20c', '20d') THEN (SELECT UDSDiagnosisCategoryID 
                                                                                   FROM UDSDiagnosisCategories
                                                                                   WHERE UDSDiagnosisCategory = 'Selected Mental Health and Substance Abuse Conditions')
    END                                           
FROM UDSDiagnosisGroups
WHERE UDSDiagnosisCategoryID IS NULL
```

The problem is that only 1 row is updated in the `UDSDiagnosisGroups` table.
The row that is updated is the one with a `LineDisplay` value of `1-2`.
All of the other values remain `NULL`.

Where am I going wrong?  It looks to me that I am following examples I found but only 1 row is updated, not all of the rows in the table.

Comment: Looks correct to me. To see why you aren't getting a match, just select the case statement, I.E. remove UPDATE UDSDiagnosisGroups SET UDSDiagnosisCategoryID =  and replace it with SELECT. Then put an ELSE LineDisplay at the end and you'll see what the LineDisplay value is when you're not getting a match.

Comment: OK.  When I do what you suggest, I get an error regarding data types.  The `LineDisplay` is a varchar(5) and the ID is an int.  But I need to base the ID on the `LineDisplay` value.  So, when the `LineDisplay` is this list of values select the ID based on the select statement.

Comment: I figured it out.  The `LineDisplay` string had an empty varchar at the start of the string.  When I trim those characters, the update works.  Thanks for the suggestion @Robert Bain.

Comment: @RobertBain - create an answer with your suggestion and I will check my question as answered.

Comment: I've added my suggestion as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest to change your code to something like this, it would be much more readable

```
UPDATE UDSDiagnosisGroups SET
    UDSDiagnosisCategoryID = d.UDSDiagnosisCategoryID 
from UDSDiagnosisGroups as g
    inner join UDSDiagnosisCategories as d on
        d.UDSDiagnosisCategory =
            case
                when g.LineDisplay in ('1-2', '3', '4', '4a', '4b') then
                    'Selected Infectious and Parasitic Diseases' 
                when g.LineDisplay in ('5', '6') then
                    'Selected Diseases of the Respiratory System'
                when g.LineDisplay in ('7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '14a') then
                    'Selected Other Medical Conditions'
                when g.LineDisplay in ('15', '16', '17') then
                    ' Selected Childhood Conditions (limited to ages 0 through 17)'
                when g.LineDisplay in ('18', '19', '19a', '20a', '20b', '20c', '20d') then
                    'Selected Mental Health and Substance Abuse Conditions'
where
    g.UDSDiagnosisCategoryID is null
```

Then you can play and do `select` instead of `update` to see if the rows returned from `UDSDiagnosisCategories` are valid. You could have some typos there. It's hard to tell more without the data.

Answer (score 0):

May be your column value is empty not Null. Use **ISNULL** and try again

```
UPDATE UDSDiagnosisGroups
SET UDSDiagnosisCategoryID = 
    CASE WHEN LineDisplay IN ('1-2', '3', '4', '4a', '4b') THEN (SELECT UDSDiagnosisCategoryID 
                                                                 FROM UDSDiagnosisCategories
                                                                 WHERE UDSDiagnosisCategory = 'Selected Infectious and Parasitic Diseases') 
         WHEN LineDisplay IN ('5', '6') THEN (SELECT UDSDiagnosisCategoryID 
                                              FROM UDSDiagnosisCategories
                                              WHERE UDSDiagnosisCategory = 'Selected Diseases of the Respiratory System')
         WHEN LineDisplay IN ('7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '14a') THEN (SELECT UDSDiagnosisCategoryID 
                                                                                        FROM UDSDiagnosisCategories
                                                                                        WHERE UDSDiagnosisCategory = 'Selected Other Medical Conditions')
         WHEN LineDisplay IN ('15', '16', '17') THEN (SELECT UDSDiagnosisCategoryID 
                                                      FROM UDSDiagnosisCategories
                                                      WHERE UDSDiagnosisCategory = ' Selected Childhood Conditions (limited to ages 0 through 17)')
         WHEN LineDisplay IN ('18', '19', '19a', '20a', '20b', '20c', '20d') THEN (SELECT UDSDiagnosisCategoryID 
                                                                                   FROM UDSDiagnosisCategories
                                                                                   WHERE UDSDiagnosisCategory = 'Selected Mental Health and Substance Abuse Conditions')
    END                                           
FROM UDSDiagnosisGroups
WHERE ISNULL(UDSDiagnosisCategoryID,'') = ''
```